# awk: one liner to calculate rounded average of two columns

Tags: awk

I have a 100-million-line tab-separated file with numbers in columns 2 and 3.

```
d1  1   4
g7  4   5
y3  11  20
```

I would like to replace column 2 with the rounded mean of columns 2 and 3, and replace column 3 with column 2 + 1.

```
d1  3   4
g7  5   6
y3  16  17
```

Is there a computationally-efficient awk one-liner to do this on large files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem to be the obvious implementation:

```
awk '{a=int(($2+$3)/2+0.5); $2=a; $3=a+1;print}'
```